# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'constructor')

Tags: javascript, node.js, mysql2, node-mysql2

please help.

I'm making use of the node-mysql2 library

I have SQL queries and whenever a query is run and some variables are null in that query it triggers this error. This is usually when the session variables are null. AgentID=Null or DealerID=Null.

The error originates from the mysql2 connection.js file

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\pavstockallocatebot\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:538
    if (sql.constructor === Commands.Query) {
            ^
    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'constructor')
```

**Where it is triggered:**

```
 query(sql, values, cb) {
    let cmdQuery;
    if (sql.constructor === Commands.Query) {
      cmdQuery = sql;
    } else {
      cmdQuery = Connection.createQuery(sql, values, cb, this.config);
    }
    this._resolveNamedPlaceholders(cmdQuery);
    const rawSql = this.format(cmdQuery.sql, cmdQuery.values !== undefined ? cmdQuery.values : []);
    cmdQuery.sql = rawSql;
    return this.addCommand(cmdQuery);
  }
```

It freezes my whole app. and doesn't allow me to restart the app.
How can I add an error handler that will check if the variables are undefined or null to avoid ever getting this error. When I do get this error to handle it appropriately.

Comment: Can you show the code that generates this error?

Comment: The error originates from the mysql2 library and the connection.js file.

I've edited the question and I've added where it is generated.

Answer (score 1):

There are many coding styles, but this is one solution.

It's crashing the app because it is an "uncaught" error.  So let's catch it.

```
try {
    //this will error
    if (sql.constructor === Commands.Query) {}
} catch(error) {
    // then you can console.log the error here
    // and do something else.
}
```

Ideally you would check to see if `sql` is truthy and that your sql connection has been established before any sort of logic can touch this part of the code.  But that can evolve into a bigger conversation around scaffolding and server logic architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this helps

```
if(sql && sql.constructor === Commands.Query)
```

or

```
if(sql?.constructor === Commands.Query)
```

Comment: Hey @Vinayak Vohra, I get the following error. 






            node:buffer:323
  throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(
  ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object. Received undefined
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:372:5)
    at Function.from (node:buffer:323:9)
    at Object.exports.encode (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\pavstockallocatebot\node_modules\mysql2\lib\parsers\string.js:20:19)